# How To Load Custom Record(mixture of normal and Json Data) using PIG

Tags: json, hadoop, apache-pig

I want to load my input file data using pig which is of this form

```
row1val1, row1val2, {row1json1}
row2val1, row2val2, {row2json2}
row3val1, row3val2, {row3json3}
...
```

I want to load the json data aloung with the row'n'val'n' (first two columns) using a defined schema , but the JsonLoader provided by PIG is unable to load it.

Please suggest alternatives or if this can be done directly using PIG.

Do I need to override or write my own JsonLoader to perform this task?

Kindly suggest.
Thanks, cheers:) !!

Comment: Is the Json is in complex structure ? If not ,Then we can do Json String to Map conversion .

Comment: to @Learner, yes the json is complex.!! Currently I have written a custom loader that is doing it for me, but it is very specific to my json and any change in that json might require a change in that custom loader as well, I want to avoid this.!! please suggest..

Answer (score 0):

Load the data as a CSV; whatever you can to get the JSON as a string field.

Try using a javascript UDF for the JSON data.  **It's not safe**, but it's simple.  I guess it depends on your trust of the data.

```
function JSON2Pig(JSONString) {
  if (JSONString == null) {
    return null;
  } else {
    obj = eval("("+JSONString+")");
    return obj;
  }

}
```